# How can input operators be added to a tensorflow graph after distributed execution has begun?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use distributed tensorflow to train on model in streaming fashion using a parameter server. The worker setup is something like this based on https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/distributed/:

```
def train_model(filenames, params):
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
            worker_device='/job:worker/task:%d' % params.task_index, cluster=cluster)):
        input_op = construct_input_op(filenames)
        global_step = tf.Variable(0)
        train_op = construct_train_op(input_op, global_step, params)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables() + tf.local_variables())

    supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(
        is_chief=params.task_index == 0,
        logdir=params.training_summary_dir,
        init_op=init_op,
        saver=saver,
        global_step=global_step,
        save_model_secs=0)

    with supervisor.managed_session(server.target) as sess: 
        while not supervisor.should_stop() and step <= params.max_steps:
            sess.run(train_op)

    supervisor.stop()

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": [params.param_server_host], "worker": params.worker_hosts})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=params.task_index)
while True:
   filenames = wait_for_new_training_data(...)
   train_model(filenames, params)
```

With this setup, I get a runtime error that the `Graph is finalized and cannot be modified` when adding input operators in the second pass. How can I make this example work?

Comment: You can try `._unsafe_unfinalize()` on your graph object, although a more robust solution would be to create all needed operations ahead of time (there are performance/thread-safety issues caused by modifying the graph while running it/concurrently)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - could you put that as your answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try ._unsafe_unfinalize() on your graph object, although a more robust solution would be to create all needed operations ahead of time (there are performance/thread-safety issues caused by modifying the graph while running it/concurrently)